# How do I set multiple headers using PostAsync in C#?

Tags: c#, httpresponse

I have some working code:

```
using (var client = new HttpClient())
{
HttpResponseMessage response;
response = client.PostAsync(Url, new StringContent(Request, Encoding.UTF8, header)).Result;
}
```

// the above works fine for a simple header, e.g. "application/json"

What do I do, if I want to have multiple headers? E.g. adding "myKey", "foo" pair and "Accept", "image/foo1"

If I try adding the following before the .Result line, intellisense complains (the word 'Headers' is in red with "Can't resolve symbol 'Headers'":

```
client.Headers.Add("myKey", "foo");
client.Headers.Add("Accept", "image/foo1");
```

Answer (score 45, accepted):

You can access the [`Headers`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.http.httpcontent.headers(v=vs.118).aspx) property through the [`StringContent`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.http.stringcontent%28v=vs.118%29.aspx):

```
var content = new StringContent(Request, Encoding.UTF8, header);
content.Headers.Add(...);
```

Then pass the StringContent to the `PostAsync` call:

```
response = client.PostAsync(Url, content).Result;
```

Comment: Ok... that helps to a degree (one set of headers was ok), but... I am now running into: Misused header name. Make sure request headers are used with HttpRequestMessage, response headers with HttpResponseMessage, and  content headers with HttpContent objects.  I am not sure if the offending set is a a response or content header.  How would I add either?

Comment: I got error saying content header is separate from request header

Answer (score 26):

I stopped using the Post/Get *Async methods in favor of the `SendAsync(...)` method and `HttpRequestMessage` 
Send Async is the big brother which allows you the full flexibility you otherwise can't achieve.

```
using System.Net.Http;

var httpRequestMessage = new HttpRequestMessage();

httpRequestMessage.Method = httpMethod;
httpRequestMessage.RequestUri = new Uri(url);

httpRequestMessage.Headers
                  .UserAgent
                  .Add(new Headers.ProductInfoHeaderValue(
                                              _applicationAssembly.Name, 
                                              _applicationAssembly.Version.ToString()));

HttpContent httpContent = new StringContent(json, Encoding.UTF8, "application/json");
switch (httpMethod.Method)
{
    case "POST":
        httpRequestMessage.Content = httpContent;
        break;
}

var result = await httpClient.SendAsync(httpRequestMessage);
result.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();
```

Comment: Looks like an interesting approach.  I will experiment with it.

Comment: FWIW, do not call `Task.Wait()` in the call stack above this. This could cause a dead-lock situation during `httpClient.SendAsync(httpRequestMessage)`. Instead make sure your stack is async/await from top to bottom or use a thread from the thread-pool.

Answer (score 7):

You can also use

```
var client = new HttpClient();
client.DefaultRequestHeaders.TryAddWithoutValidation("headername","headervalue");
```

If you want to just set the headers on the HttpClient class just once.  Here is the [MSDN docs](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh875107(v=vs.118).aspx) on `DefaultRequestHeaders.TryAddWithoutValidation`

Comment: Definitely, Clean approach to use the custom headers, Otherwise, you'll see an Exception.